# How can I apply a filter projection ([?port == `eth1`]) on top of an object projection (*)?

Tags: json, jmespath

I have a data structure like that

```json
{
  "lan": {
    "main_router": {
      "ip": "192.168.22.1",
      "port": "eth1"
    }
  },
  "guest": {
    "main_router": {
      "ip": "192.168.44.1",
      "port": "eth1.44"
    }
  },
  "iot": {
    "main_router": {
      "ip": "192.168.66.1",
      "port": "eth1.66"
    }
  }
}
```

and I want to get all `main_router` entries where the value of `port` is `eth1`.

I tried the following two queries on the jmespath.org tutorial:

```
*.main_router[?port==`eth1`]
*[?main_router.port==`eth1`]
```

but neither this two nor the many variations I tried did yield any result at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `*` is an *object projection* and if you want to apply a projection on the result of another projection — and not on the projection itself — you need to stop the first projection, with the help of a [*pipe expression*](https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html#pipe-expressions).

Which you can apply to either of your trial:

```
*.main_router | [?port == `eth1`]
```

Would give you:

```json
[
  {
    "ip": "192.168.22.1",
    "port": "eth1"
  }
]
```

While

```
* | [?main_router.port == `eth1`]
```

Would give you:

```json
[
  {
    "main_router": {
      "ip": "192.168.22.1",
      "port": "eth1"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Thank you so very much!
I did not see it here: https://jmespath.org/specification.html#pipe-expressions